# Failed to load viewstate with statically created controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

---

### Edit, this is fixed, and I have posted my answer, but StackOverflow denies me marking this as the answer for at least 2 days.

I have an ASPX page which defines a wizard with wizard steps - this is within a User Control.

I place this user control on two different pages, both which want to use the wizard steps, but not all of them. For this I am removing some of the wizard steps by using the following command within my `Page_Load` event:

```
wizard.WizardSteps.Remove(wizardStepControl)
```

If I try to click one of the wizard steps to navigate to that tab.. I get the following error:

> "Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is
>   being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request"

I need the viewstate to be enabled otherwise my controls within the wizard steps are lost. I am not readding the wizard steps, or removing any more after the first upload.

I realise I can do this within the Page_Init event, but unfortunately this isn't feasible for me, as I depend on a local variable which is set when loading this control from the parent control, so I know whether or not to remove the wizard steps - so this must be from the `Page_Load` or after (from my testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this, although I'm sure it's not an elegant way.

I have placed a variable on my parent page, which I am then setting during the parent page's Page_PreInit event. Then when the child control (with the wizard controls) is loading, during the control's `Page_Init` event I check the parent's variable using:

```
If DirectCast(Parent.Page, ParentPageAspx).RemoveWizardSteps Then
    ....
```

This allows my me to check whether to remove the wizard steps during the control's `Page_Init`, which then fixes the problem with the `ViewState` being different.

I'm marking this as my answer, but if anyone else has a better suggestion (which there must be!) then I will mark accordingly.

Cheers.